# Choosing a CRAN repository

Tags: r, cran

While choosing CRAN repository what is the URL of CRAN repository?Where can i found complete listing of CRAN repositories on www.r-project.org? I don't know the URL of CRAN repository? I wrote a command >available.packages() Then R told me to select CRAN mirror from the window that appeared on the screen. After selecting India, List of available packages appeared.

Comment: Then you chose a repository. Or more accurately, you chose a mirror of the repository, which is fine. You can use `install.packages` to install any packages that you want.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html